# Como declarar um vetor com 2 posições?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho um exercício com o seguinte enunciado:

> Escreva uma classe cujos objetos representam alunos matriculados em uma disciplina. Cada objeto dessa classe deve guardar os seguintes dados do aluno: **matrícula**, **nome**, 2 **notas de prova** e 1 **nota de trabalho**. Escreva os seguintes métodos para esta classe:
>
> **media:** calcula a média final do aluno (cada prova tem peso 2,5 e o trabalho tem peso 2)
>
> **final:** calcula quanto o aluno precisa para a prova final (retorna zero se ele não for para a final)

Meu código está assim:

```
public class Aluno {
    private String matricula;
    private String nome;
    private double notaProva;
    private double notaTrabalho;

    public void media(double nota1, double nota2) {
        this.notaProva = nota1;
        this.notaTrabalho = nota2;

        double mediaPonderada;
        mediaPonderada = ((this.notaProva*2.5+this.notaTrabalho*2)/(2+2.5));
        System.out.println("Média final: "+ mediaPonderada);
    }
    public void resultadoFinal() {


    }
    public void detalhes() {
        System.out.println("Nome: "+this.nome);
        System.out.println("Matricula: "+ this.matricula);
        System.out.println("Nota da prova: "+ this.notaProva);
        System.out.println("Nota do trabalho: "+ this.notaTrabalho);

    }
    public String getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }
    public void setMatricula(String matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
}
```

```
public class PrincipalMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Aluno aluno = new Aluno();
        aluno.setNome("Magno");
        aluno.setMatricula("20194456458");
        aluno.media(9, 5);
        aluno.detalhes();           
    }    
}
```

Como eu faço para declarar um vetor no atributo **`notaProva`** com 2 posições?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para definir que o tipo de uma variável é um *array* é necessário usar colchetes, por exemplo:

```
private double[] notasProvas;
```

Em Java não é possível declarar um *array* e já definir a quantidade de posições. O tamanho sempre precisa ser definido na inicialização.

No seu caso, imagino que a melhor saída é definir um construtor para a classe e inicializar o *array* neste construtor.

```
public class Aluno {
    // ... outros campos

    private double[] notasProvas;

    public Aluno() {
        notasProvas = new double[2];
    }
}
```

Claro que, depois disto, você precisará pensar em como vai ficar a estrutura do(s) *getters* e *setters*.

Answer (score 0):

Quando você quiser declarar um vetor, use colchetes. Exemplo: `double vetor1 [];`

Ao declarar o seu tamanho e conteúdo, pode-se inserir diretamente os dados da seguinte forma: `vetor1 = {x1, x2};`

Ou você pode criar um vetor vazio, e preenchê-lo durante a execução do programa: `vetor1 = new double[2];`

Espero ter ajudado